# How to change the font of Electronjs DevTools autocomplete listbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

Is there any possibility to change the font of autocomplete listbox shown when typing in Electronjs DevTools console.

Most of the fonts of Chrome DevTools are same as Electronjs DevTools, the autocomplete list box in Electronjs has different font than Chrome.

The difference can be seen here:

[ElectronDevTools-ChromeDevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfcIN.png)